# Dhru Api - getting customer input

Tags: php, json, api

I try to make dhru api based on this code https://github.com/dhru/dhru-fusion-api-standards .
My problem is to get customer input on web which is sent by dhru web in parameters.

I already determinated what exacly website send to my API:

```
[username] => login

[apiaccesskey] => pass

[action] => placeimeiorder

[requestformat] => JSON

[parameters] => <PARAMETERS><ID>100</ID><CUSTOMFIELD>eyJ1ZGlkIjoiMDAwMDgwMjAtMDAxQzM0MTIyNjgxMDAyRSJ9</CUSTOMFIELD><MODELID></MODELID><PROVIDERID></PROVIDERID><NETWORK></NETWORK><PIN></PIN><KBH></KBH><MEP></MEP><PRD></PRD><TYPE></TYPE><LOCKS></LOCKS><REFERENCE></REFERENCE><IMEI>423545675567658</IMEI><udid>00008020-001C34122681002E</udid></PARAMETERS>
```

But i'm unable to get any value from this parameters.

I already tried all of this but nothing work:

```
1) $udid = json_decode($parameters['udid'],true);
2) $udid = $parameters['udid'];
3) $imei = $parameters['IMEI'];
4) $udid = (string)$parameters['udid'];
```

Can somebody give me advice?

Comment: I understand that dhru fusion send to api POST varriable "parameters", so I use $parameters = json_decode($parameters, true); to decode json and after that $OrderID = (int)$parameters['ID']; to get value but nothing work with this.

Comment: Even in their example https://github.com/dhru/dhru-fusion-api-standards this $OrderID = (int)$parameters['ID']; dont get value.

Comment: other POST value like username, action , apisecurekey works good